# How to handle the column mismatch in datatable in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular6

If all the conditions are satisfied and true then all columns are matched and shown in datatable like:

[image]

client.auditorGroup is either true or false. The codes working is:

```
    <table class="table table-bodered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Mag No</th>
         <th>SelectionDate</th>
         <th> SelectedBy</th>
         <th>PanEximNumber</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>PhoneNumber</th>
         <th>SelectionType</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let client of clients" (click)="onClick(client)">
      <td  [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
      <td>{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
      <td>{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
      <td>{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{client.name}}</td>
      <td>{{client.address}}</td>
      <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit
      Delete</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

At this last condition if it is false then the datatable becomes like column mismatch due to this statement:

```
<td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit
          Delete</td>
```

[image]

Comment: clAs a workaround why not show blank `td` at the end based on `client.auditorGroup ` value

Comment: can you please clarify what is the expected behavior?

Comment: were you be able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for them on HTML templating or create a function that returns true if found them all and add it to *[ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) condition.

Demo:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr 
  *ngFor="let client of clients"
  *ngIf="client.selectionId&&
  client.selectedBy&&
  client.panEximNumber&&
  client.name&&
  client.phoneNumber&&
  client.selectionType" 
  (click)="onClick(client)">
    <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
    <td>{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{client.name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.address}}</td>
    <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit Delete
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Second way:

```js
clientHasFullData() {

  return this.client.selectionId &&
    this.client.selectedBy &&
    this.client.panEximNumber &&
    this.client.name &&
    this.client.phoneNumber &&
    this.client.selectionType
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let client of clients" *ngIf="clientHasFullData()" (click)="onClick(client)">
    <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
    <td>{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{client.name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.address}}</td>
    <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="getStyle(this.client)">Edit Delete
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is usually because the data is not available for the column. So when the last   table header is there. Its expecting a data column as well but since you are using ngif and its false the last column is null. but the header is expecting a column. place ngif on the header as well that should solve the problem.

```
    <th *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup">Action</th>
```

Comment: *ngFor is iterated from <tbody> block not from <thead>